# Can't get property '_id' and 'title' or 'imageUrl' in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi im developing nodejs express app. I am getting exceptions and don't know why. Everything seems to be perfect for me.

Can't get property `'_id'` and `'title'` or `'imageUrl'` in Express
help me out...

Comment: You should share the exceptions here.

Comment: Just use below middlewares to get values

Comment: Hope it works for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `app.js` `(server.js)` or your root file of the app

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

It parses your request and you get all values...